# Event-calendar style dates for own category

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there some easy way to add event-calendar plugin style dates to my own category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of without a plugin (only because I don't know of any plugins that do exactly that) is creating a custom post type for it. If you have any understanding of PHP it may be easier than you suspect. You would just add a date field and create a single template file for that type - single-event.php, if the custom type was named 'event'.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Post_Types